# Moving Uploaded Files to Another Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In a ASP.NET web application, I am using the following code to move uploaded files to an archive folder. When the following code executes, I receive the following error message: "Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

The code listed below is failing on the file.MoveTo call.

What is causing this error?

NOTE: Five files exists in the UploadedXML folder. The Uploaded\Archive folder does not contain any files.

```
'Move Uploaded file to Archive Folder.
Dim di As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("UploadedXML"))

For Each file As FileInfo In di.GetFiles
    file.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("UploadedXML/Archive"))
Next
```

Comment: you need move file to file, not file to folder

Comment: Thanks Hien Nguyen!  By appending the file name, it works. file.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("UploadedXML/Archive/") & file.Name)